# CNN classifier unable to classify images in a given dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I used the following code on a training dataset of 40 images of flowers but the CNN classifier fails to classify it.]

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape = (32, 32, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 4, activation = 'softmax'))

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = 
train_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\\Users\\vinay\\flowerclassification\\dataset\\train',
                                             target_size = (32, 32),
                                             batch_size = 8
                                             )
val_set = 
val_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\\Users\\vinay\\flowerclassification\\dataset\\val',
                                        target_size = (32, 32),
                                       batch_size = 8)

model.fit(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = 10,
                     epochs = 25,
                     validation_data = val_set,
                     validation_steps = 4)



model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

### /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1940: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
warnings.warn('`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and '

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 model.fit_generator(training_set,steps_per_epoch = 10,epochs = 25,validation_data = val_set,validation_steps = 2)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in **getitem**(self, idx)
55                              'but the Sequence '
56                              'has length {length}'.format(idx=idx,
---> 57                                                           length=len(self)))
58         if self.seed is not None:
59             np.random.seed(self.seed + self.total_batches_seen)

ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0

also this message is printed in the previous step:
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.

Comment: Welcome Vinay Venugopal, please post the error message with `python-traceback`. For more information look [here](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports). As we dont have the input data we cant help you. Please provide information which variable have what values at the moment of error. You could start a debug session or print them out on the line before the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try again executing the same above code by removing `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` from `model.fit`:

```
model.fit(training_set,
          #steps_per_epoch = 10,
          epochs = 25,
          validation_data = val_set,
         # validation_steps = 4
          )
```

`Steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` are not correct.
Removing these from model will itself count the `steps_per_epoch` as per given `images_count` and `batch_size`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70060431/why-is-model-training-for-only-one-epoch-when-ive-mentioned-15-is-whats-requir/70474911#70474911) similar answer for reference.

As from warning, it shows `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated. You can use `model.fit` instead to remove the warning. Please let us know if the issue still persists.