# Why is model training for only one epoch when I've mentioned 15 is what's required?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('training_set',
                                                    batch_size=250,
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    target_size=(150, 150))
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('test_set',
                                                              batch_size=456,
                                                              class_mode='binary',
                                                              target_size=(150, 150))
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    epochs=15,
    steps_per_epoch=22,
    validation_steps=22,
    verbose=1
)
```

I'm trying to classify cats and dogs here. Here's the link to the dataset on Kaggle if you want to reproduce this thing yourself: https://www.kaggle.com/tongpython/cat-and-dog.

In the `model.fit()` function, I've specified `epochs=15`. But when I run this, it goes on until it finished 1/15 epochs. Have a look:

```
Epoch 1/15
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_train_function.<locals>.train_function at 0x16882d280> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
WARNING: AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_train_function.<locals>.train_function at 0x16882d280> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
2021-11-21 19:10:51.086856: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-11-21 19:10:51.087052: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:126] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
22/22 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.5458 - accuracy: 0.5119 WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_test_function.<locals>.test_function at 0x1699b7670> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
WARNING: AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_test_function.<locals>.test_function at 0x1699b7670> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
```

Do you know why this is happening and what I can do to get my 15 epochs' worth of accuracy?

Comment: Try setting your batch size in your data generators to match. Also, are you sure your batch size should be that large?

Comment: There are 10032 images in the dataset; 456 divides 10032 perfectly. Should that be smaller?

Comment: @Djinn I thought batch size * steps per epoch should equal or be close to the number of files, right? What do you think would be a suitable batch size?

Comment: It's preference, but I've never seen anyone use a batch size that high and I think that's what's causing the issue. Try size 32 or something. You might want to do some more reading on Keras model creation.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `batch_size` is way high for training 2000 images with 22 `steps_per_epoch`.

Here you need to understand the calculation of `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps`.

```
#Steps_per_epoch = no. of training images/ batch_size   (2000/250)=7.8
#validation_steps= no. of testing images/ batch_size    (1000/456)=2.19
```

Also, `batch_size` should be among these numbers (8,16,32,64,128,256) though there is no restrictions.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(training_set,
                                                    batch_size=128,
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    target_size=(150, 150))
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_set,
                                                              batch_size=128,
                                                              class_mode='binary',
                                                              target_size=(150, 150))
```

You can see changed `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` as per `batch_size=128`

```
print(2000/128)  #steps_per_epoch=number of training images/batch_size
print(1000/128)  #validation_steps=number of testing images/batch_size
```

Output:

```
15.625
7.8125
```

If you don't define `steps_per_epoch`, model will calculate `steps_per_epoch` itself with given images count and `batch_size` as calculated above.

```
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    epochs=15,
                    verbose=1)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/15
16/16 [==============================] - 23s 2s/step - loss: 0.4897 - accuracy: 0.7725 - val_loss: 0.6596 - val_accuracy: 0.6280
Epoch 2/15
16/16 [==============================] - 36s 2s/step - loss: 0.4133 - accuracy: 0.8060 - val_loss: 0.6691 - val_accuracy: 0.6890
Epoch 3/15
16/16 [==============================] - 21s 1s/step - loss: 0.4430 - accuracy: 0.7950 - val_loss: 0.7110 - val_accuracy: 0.6750
Epoch 4/15
16/16 [==============================] - 19s 1s/step - loss: 0.3299 - accuracy: 0.8560 - val_loss: 0.7929 - val_accuracy: 0.6710
Epoch 5/15
16/16 [==============================] - 14s 905ms/step - loss: 0.3536 - accuracy: 0.8355 - val_loss: 0.6888 - val_accuracy: 0.6440
Epoch 6/15
16/16 [==============================] - 15s 968ms/step - loss: 0.2486 - accuracy: 0.9010 - val_loss: 0.7898 - val_accuracy: 0.6540
Epoch 7/15
16/16 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.3154 - accuracy: 0.8975 - val_loss: 0.7504 - val_accuracy: 0.6420
Epoch 8/15
16/16 [==============================] - 14s 905ms/step - loss: 0.1612 - accuracy: 0.9505 - val_loss: 1.0349 - val_accuracy: 0.6390
Epoch 9/15
16/16 [==============================] - 14s 907ms/step - loss: 0.1609 - accuracy: 0.9415 - val_loss: 1.1632 - val_accuracy: 0.6350
Epoch 10/15
16/16 [==============================] - 14s 904ms/step - loss: 0.0781 - accuracy: 0.9765 - val_loss: 1.1445 - val_accuracy: 0.7020
Epoch 11/15
16/16 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.2899 - accuracy: 0.9170 - val_loss: 0.9464 - val_accuracy: 0.6930
Epoch 12/15
16/16 [==============================] - 15s 916ms/step - loss: 0.0563 - accuracy: 0.9855 - val_loss: 1.1374 - val_accuracy: 0.6730
Epoch 13/15
16/16 [==============================] - 16s 1s/step - loss: 0.0347 - accuracy: 0.9930 - val_loss: 1.4902 - val_accuracy: 0.6740
Epoch 14/15
16/16 [==============================] - 16s 990ms/step - loss: 0.1873 - accuracy: 0.9430 - val_loss: 1.1990 - val_accuracy: 0.6940
Epoch 15/15
16/16 [==============================] - 15s 919ms/step - loss: 0.0848 - accuracy: 0.9775 - val_loss: 2.5946 - val_accuracy: 0.5520
```